# Error 404 File not found en GitHub Pages

Tags: github

Llevo un buen rato intentando subir un proyecto a GitHub, pero al momento de actualizar la página y probar el link me da este error. Ya lo borré, volví a subir, le cambié de nombre y un montón de cosas pero no encuentro el inconveniente.
Link del proyecto: https://yanisita.github.io/batatabit/
Repo: https://github.com/yanisita/batatabit/tree/master/BataBit

Answer (score 0):

Para publicar su página en Github debe ir al repositorio de dicho proyecto y debe dar clic en el menú **Settings** - **Pages** y en la opción **Source** seleccione la rama *master* y luego seleccione la opción *root*, posteriormente debe dar clic en **Save**.